# Why does my generated assembly with interface implement as methods instead of as property?

Tags: c#, typebuilder

The following code creates an assembly called MyAssembly.dll which contains a single interface called IMyType. IMyType has a single property called my property.

```
string assemblyName = "MyAssembly";

AssemblyBuilder assemblyBuilder =
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly(
        new AssemblyName(assemblyName),
        AssemblyBuilderAccess.RunAndSave
    );

ModuleBuilder moduleBuilder =
    assemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicModule(
        assemblyName,
        $"{assemblyName}.dll",
        true
    );

TypeBuilder typeBuilder =
    moduleBuilder.DefineType(
        $"{assemblyName}.IMyType",
        TypeAttributes.Public |
        TypeAttributes.Interface |
        TypeAttributes.Abstract
    );

PropertyBuilder propertyBuilder =
    typeBuilder.DefineProperty(
        "MyProperty",
        System.Reflection.PropertyAttributes.HasDefault |
        System.Reflection.PropertyAttributes.SpecialName,
        typeof(int),
        null
    );

MethodBuilder getBuilder =
    typeBuilder.DefineMethod(
        "get_MyProperty",
        MethodAttributes.Virtual |
        MethodAttributes.Abstract |
        MethodAttributes.SpecialName,
        typeof(int),
        Type.EmptyTypes
    );
MethodBuilder setBuilder =
    typeBuilder.DefineMethod(
        "set_MyProperty",
        MethodAttributes.Virtual |
        MethodAttributes.Abstract |
        MethodAttributes.SpecialName,
        typeof(int),
        Type.EmptyTypes
    );

propertyBuilder.SetGetMethod(getBuilder);
propertyBuilder.SetSetMethod(setBuilder);

typeBuilder.CreateType();

assemblyBuilder.Save($"{assemblyName}.dll");
```

When I decompile the assembly in DotPeek I see the code I expect to see:

[image]

In another project however that references this assembly I create a class that implements my new IMyType and visual studio creates this:
[image]

What do I need to do so that visual studio will see this as an auto property instead of two methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably, you should define your `set` method as void and taking one argument of type int.

```
MethodBuilder setBuilder =
    typeBuilder.DefineMethod(
        "set_MyProperty",
        MethodAttributes.Virtual |
        MethodAttributes.Abstract |
        MethodAttributes.SpecialName,
        typeof(void),
        new[] { typeof(int) }
    );
```